# ActiveMQ property SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES sending ObjectMessage

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, serializable

Running a simple project using SpringBoot and creating an ActiveMQ broker through  @Configuration.

In the Main-method, before SpringApplication.run, I set this;

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES", "*");
```

Trusting all packages when creating the broker and ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

```
factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
```

Route:

```
from("timer://getStuffDone?period=5s") //just a test
    .to("bean://superProcessor?method=process")  // new a simple object and puts it as body
    .to("activemq:queue:superQueue?jmsMessageType=Object");
```

The object:

```
public class SuperObject {
public String name;}
```

BUT, I get this:

Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: net.supertest.SuperObject to the required type: java.io.Serializable with value net.supertest.SuperObject@2b38b4cb at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:206) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createJmsMessageForType(JmsBinding.java:672) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]

If I implement Serializable, it works well.., but I was expecting it handle that automaticly as I had used the wildcard in SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES.
Any clues on why it's not working as expected?
ActiveMQ version 5.15.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the property `org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES` does not relieve you of implementing `Serializable`. It is just a security setting on the broker to block ObjectMessage marshal/unmarshal by default.

To allow ObjectMessage serialization you have to configure the needed packages on the broker with `org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES` and on the client with `factory.setTrustedPackages`.

Regardless of this configuration you have to implement your Object as `Serializable`.

From the [ActiveMQ Docs](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html):

> ObjectMessage objects depend on Java serialization of marshal/unmarshal object payload. **This process is generally considered unsafe** as malicious payload can exploit the host system. That's why starting with versions 5.12.2 and 5.13.0, ActiveMQ **enforces users to explicitly whitelist packages** that can be exchanged using ObjectMessages.

Comment: Dang. ... Thank you for the answer!